# Ruby array of characters to to byte array (of hex chars) for bluetooth transfer

Tags: c, ruby, bluetooth

I supposed to be passing a byte array (I guess c terminology for a string?) to an api used for Bluetooth communication. What I'm trying to pass is this array, joined as a string:

```
["\xA6", "\x9E", "\x00", "\x14", "\x00", "\x8E", "\x00", "{", "\"", "s", "i", "t", "e", "_", "n", "a", "m", "e", "\"", ":", "1", "1", "5", "8", "5", "4", "}", "\xF5"]
```

However, this fails silently, the expected format seems to be:

```
a69e0014008e007b22736974655f6e616d65223a3131353835347df5
```

I can see that Ruby has a string method bytes.to_a which would give me

```
[166, 158, 0, 20, 0, 142, 0, 123, 34, 115, 105, 116, 101, 95, 110, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 49, 49, 53, 56, 53, 52, 125, 245]
```

But I'd like to pull out the hex values for each byte and then .join them. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Or am I approaching this incorrectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a binary string:

```
s = "\xA6\x9E\x00\x14\x00\x8E\x00{\"site_name\":115854}\xF5"
```

You can use [`unpack1`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-unpack1) with `H*` (hex string, high nibble first):

```
s.unpack1('H*') #=> "a69e0014008e007b22736974655f6e616d65223a3131353835347df5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would suffice. I'm not clear still whether the byte array and string are "equivalent" in ruby

```
intarr=["\xA6", "\x9E", "\x00", "\x14", "\x00", "\x8E", "\x00", "{", "\"", "s", "i", "t", "e", "_", "n", "a", "m", "e", "\"", ":", "1", "1", "5", "8", "5", "4", "}", "\xF5"].join.bytes.to_a
strres=""
intarr.each do |x|
  strres=strres+x.to_s(16)
end
puts strres
```

Comment: Note that `0.to_s(16)` gives `"0"`, not `"00"`.